# Android Studio Excecution fail

Tags: android, android-studio

Hi I'm new in Android & Android Studio.
I googled but didn't find a solution.
I don't get an error after a build, but when I execute the app it won't start and this error pops up.
Does someone know what this error means?

```
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:dexDebug'.
> com.android.ide.common.internal.LoggedErrorException: Failed to run command:
    C:\Users\Bökrn\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\build-tools\21.1.2\dx.bat --dex --no-optimize --output C:\Users\Bökrn\Documents\Android Studio\EscapeTheLabyrinth\app\build\intermediates\dex\debug --input-list=C:\Users\Bökrn\Documents\Android Studio\EscapeTheLabyrinth\app\build\intermediates\tmp\dex\debug\inputList.txt
Error Code:
    1
Output:
    UNEXPECTED TOP-LEVEL EXCEPTION:
    java.lang.RuntimeException: C:\Users\BÃ¶krn\Documents\Android Studio\EscapeTheLabyrinth\app\build\intermediates\classes\debug: file not found
        at com.android.dex.util.FileUtils.readFile(FileUtils.java:51)
        at com.android.dx.cf.direct.ClassPathOpener.processOne(ClassPathOpener.java:169)
        at com.android.dx.cf.direct.ClassPathOpener.process(ClassPathOpener.java:144)
        at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.processOne(Main.java:632)
        at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.processAllFiles(Main.java:510)
        at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.runMonoDex(Main.java:280)
        at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.run(Main.java:246)
        at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.main(Main.java:215)
        at com.android.dx.command.Main.main(Main.java:106)
    UNEXPECTED TOP-LEVEL EXCEPTION:
    java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\Users\BÃ¶krn\Documents\Android Studio\EscapeTheLabyrinth\app\build\intermediates\pre-dexed\debug\support-annotations-21.0.3-34ed34beb77e7600ab44333dd9bca10ca8f3aba5.jar (Das System kann den angegebenen Pfad nicht finden)
        at java.util.zip.ZipFile.open(Native Method)
        at java.util.zip.ZipFile.<init>(ZipFile.java:220)
        at java.util.zip.ZipFile.<init>(ZipFile.java:150)
        at java.util.zip.ZipFile.<init>(ZipFile.java:164)
        at com.android.dx.cf.direct.ClassPathOpener.processArchive(ClassPathOpener.java:244)
        at com.android.dx.cf.direct.ClassPathOpener.processOne(ClassPathOpener.java:166)
        at com.android.dx.cf.direct.ClassPathOpener.process(ClassPathOpener.java:144)
        at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.processOne(Main.java:632)
        at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.processAllFiles(Main.java:510)
        at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.runMonoDex(Main.java:280)
        at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.run(Main.java:246)
        at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.main(Main.java:215)
        at com.android.dx.command.Main.main(Main.java:106)
    UNEXPECTED TOP-LEVEL EXCEPTION:
    java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\Users\BÃ¶krn\Documents\Android Studio\EscapeTheLabyrinth\app\build\intermediates\pre-dexed\debug\classes-ce42d90494b94b8131da1da601a38af71ff06700.jar (Das System kann den angegebenen Pfad nicht finden)
        at java.util.zip.ZipFile.open(Native Method)
        at java.util.zip.ZipFile.<init>(ZipFile.java:220)
        at java.util.zip.ZipFile.<init>(ZipFile.java:150)
        at java.util.zip.ZipFile.<init>(ZipFile.java:164)
        at com.android.dx.cf.direct.ClassPathOpener.processArchive(ClassPathOpener.java:244)
        at com.android.dx.cf.direct.ClassPathOpener.processOne(ClassPathOpener.java:166)
        at com.android.dx.cf.direct.ClassPathOpener.process(ClassPathOpener.java:144)
        at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.processOne(Main.java:632)
        at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.processAllFiles(Main.java:510)
        at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.runMonoDex(Main.java:280)
        at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.run(Main.java:246)
        at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.main(Main.java:215)
        at com.android.dx.command.Main.main(Main.java:106)
    UNEXPECTED TOP-LEVEL EXCEPTION:
    java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\Users\BÃ¶krn\Documents\Android Studio\EscapeTheLabyrinth\app\build\intermediates\pre-dexed\debug\internal_impl-21.0.3-e937203fc1a49a4726a1a1122ecf55f24ce4007b.jar (Das System kann den angegebenen Pfad nicht finden)
        at java.util.zip.ZipFile.open(Native Method)
        at java.util.zip.ZipFile.<init>(ZipFile.java:220)
        at java.util.zip.ZipFile.<init>(ZipFile.java:150)
        at java.util.zip.ZipFile.<init>(ZipFile.java:164)
        at com.android.dx.cf.direct.ClassPathOpener.processArchive(ClassPathOpener.java:244)
        at com.android.dx.cf.direct.ClassPathOpener.processOne(ClassPathOpener.java:166)
        at com.android.dx.cf.direct.ClassPathOpener.process(ClassPathOpener.java:144)
        at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.processOne(Main.java:632)
        at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.processAllFiles(Main.java:510)
        at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.runMonoDex(Main.java:280)
        at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.run(Main.java:246)
        at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.main(Main.java:215)
        at com.android.dx.command.Main.main(Main.java:106)
    UNEXPECTED TOP-LEVEL EXCEPTION:
    java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\Users\BÃ¶krn\Documents\Android Studio\EscapeTheLabyrinth\app\build\intermediates\pre-dexed\debug\classes-9af5f3d39f0d14b8942e05b1a40eb987b7ae4a8f.jar (Das System kann den angegebenen Pfad nicht finden)
        at java.util.zip.ZipFile.open(Native Method)
        at java.util.zip.ZipFile.<init>(ZipFile.java:220)
        at java.util.zip.ZipFile.<init>(ZipFile.java:150)
        at java.util.zip.ZipFile.<init>(ZipFile.java:164)
        at com.android.dx.cf.direct.ClassPathOpener.processArchive(ClassPathOpener.java:244)
        at com.android.dx.cf.direct.ClassPathOpener.processOne(ClassPathOpener.java:166)
        at com.android.dx.cf.direct.ClassPathOpener.process(ClassPathOpener.java:144)
        at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.processOne(Main.java:632)
        at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.processAllFiles(Main.java:510)
        at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.runMonoDex(Main.java:280)
        at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.run(Main.java:246)
        at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.main(Main.java:215)
        at com.android.dx.command.Main.main(Main.java:106)
    UNEXPECTED TOP-LEVEL EXCEPTION:
    java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\Users\BÃ¶krn\Documents\Android Studio\EscapeTheLabyrinth\app\build\intermediates\pre-dexed\debug\classes-05601986a7c61ca6fc106a4b417af1133e4d9786.jar (Das System kann den angegebenen Pfad nicht finden)
        at java.util.zip.ZipFile.open(Native Method)
        at java.util.zip.ZipFile.<init>(ZipFile.java:220)
        at java.util.zip.ZipFile.<init>(ZipFile.java:150)
        at java.util.zip.ZipFile.<init>(ZipFile.java:164)
        at com.android.dx.cf.direct.ClassPathOpener.processArchive(ClassPathOpener.java:244)
        at com.android.dx.cf.direct.ClassPathOpener.processOne(ClassPathOpener.java:166)
        at com.android.dx.cf.direct.ClassPathOpener.process(ClassPathOpener.java:144)
        at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.processOne(Main.java:632)
        at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.processAllFiles(Main.java:510)
        at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.runMonoDex(Main.java:280)
        at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.run(Main.java:246)
        at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.main(Main.java:215)
        at com.android.dx.command.Main.main(Main.java:106)
    6 errors; aborting
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've solved the problem. I had an 'ö' in my username, so android studio could not find the paths